# What is the problem with extrapolating a rate change to its limit?

Tags: fallacies

A recent investigation into universities in Northville reveals that the percentage of philosophy prefessors who are female was 11.2486102% in 2012, 10.9399783% in 2013 and 10.6400161% in 2014. This is very alarming because it tells us that in only 37 years , 6 months and 15 days, female philosophy professors will constitute less than 0.33333333% of Northville teaching force. What are the main problems of this question

Comment: This is **not** a question about philosophy of mathematics in any relevant sense. This is a standard issue fallacy question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Spurious precision. It would be impossible to have percentages that precise unless there were tens of millions of professors in Northville.
2. Correlation vs causation. A declining percentage of female professors over time doesn't mean there is some definite cause that can form the grounds for projecting the correlation into the future. Without some plausible story about why this is happening, it could be just natural variation rather than a trend. The fact that you have just three data points doesn't help either - it is not enough to be significant. Even if you can identify a causal story about why it is happening, it does not imply that it is projectible a long way into the future. People and societies are complex and not so predictable.
3. The reference class problem. Why pick on just philosophy professors over a three year period? Is the same trend observable for other faculties? For other College employees? For other residents of Northville?
4. Cherry picking. How was this data obtained? Was it mined or randomly selected? Was any attempt made to ensure it is representative? Have any other falsifiable predictions been made that could be used to test the hypothesis?

Comment: The cia world factbook is one of the most reliable sources for worldwide statistics. According to it only 99 % of germans are literate- with a population of 80.716 million people, this means a straggeering 807,160 germans cant read! But working from the same source , we see that only 351,100 canadians have trouble reading, clearly canandas education system is superiror at teaching is citizens to read ? Is there  a problem with this question?

Comment: Most of the same points apply. There is too little data, and it may have been cherry picked. And it jumps directly from some data about the proportions of literate citizens to a claim about how this was caused - through differences in the education system. Without further investigation, no such claim is justified. It could be, for example, that most of the illiterate Germans are immigrants who weren't educated in Germany. Also, any inference drawn from statistical data expressed as proportions or percentages is potentially vulnerable to Simpson's paradox.

Comment: In Northville 30% of the population is over 60 years old. Whereas the percentage of the population aged over 60 in southvill is just 10% . so the combined population of both northvill and southville, the percentage of people older than 60% is 20%?